# How to get count of recently added items which have "New" tag in sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

Im using sharepoint **Data View Web Part**, I just want to get the **Count** of recently added items count from list mean which have **"NEW"** tags

[image]

the above image has two new items so it should show **"2"** in count ...

Comment: How are you trying to fetch the data? JavaScript?

Comment: No,we are  using default data viewer webpart.

Comment: You can change in XSLT file of  data view web part.  Add your business logic in XSLT file and data view web part to site.

Comment: You could just count items where the created date is greater than or equal to 3 midnight's in the past.  So let's say I created an item right now (12/24 9:26 am). It's marked new because it was created after 12/22 12am.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSLink to add both the jQuery library and an external .js on the data view web part like this:

```
~site/Style%20Library/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js|~site/Style%20Library/js/newitemscount.js
```

and add the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var newItemsCount = $(".ms-newdocument-iconouter").length + " new items";
    $("#pageTitle").append(newItemsCount).wrap("<span/>")
});
```